# preg_match :print: class matches tab character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 255; $i++)
    if (preg_match('@[[:print:]]@', chr($i))) echo "chr($i) matches :print:<br>"; else echo "chr($i) doesnt match :print:<br>";
```

On my Windows system, the output for `chr(9)` is:

> chr(9) matches :print:

With the same code, on a Linux system, the output is:

> chr(9) doesnt match :print:

Why does the `:print:` class match `\t` on Windows only?

- PHP 5.5.12

Comment: + 1 for nice observation. :)

Comment: Not sure, but `:print:` is ASCII `\x20 - \x7E` or `32 - 126`

Answer (score 2):

It could be a locale issue, but then you must have a very funky locale on your hands. POSIX says that no `cntrl` can be `print`, and no `space` or `blank` can be `print` unless it's the space character itself. In the `"C"` locale, tab is *all* of `cntrl`, `space`, and `blank`; it seems like a very strange locale that would consider it none of those.

Answer (score 2):

Strange issue, because it should not match `\t` at all. The POSIX Class `[:print:]` matches printed characters and space. (anything except *control characters*)

```
[^\t\n\r\f\v]
```

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question! After searching in the pcre doc (http://pcre.org/pcre.txt), it seems that:

`[:print:] This matches the same  characters  as  [:graph:]  plus  space characters  that  are  not controls, that is, characters with the Zs property.`

> [:graph:] This matches characters that have glyphs that mark  the  page
>                    when printed. In Unicode property terms, it matches all characters with the L, M, N, P, S, or Cf properties, except for:
>
> ```
>                U+061C           Arabic Letter Mark
>                U+180E           Mongolian Vowel Separator
>                U+2066 - U+2069  Various "isolate"s`
> ```

`Zs         Space separator`

According to these definitions, it seems that your Windows system does seen the tab character as a control character. I can't say you more on the subject and wish you to live old and to have many children.